# Align Buttons in next row when there is no space left in form

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a WPF form with multiple buttons in one row. When you resize the form it should show the buttons which would be cut off in the next row. How can I do that?

```
<DockPanel Height="700" Margin="0,0,0,40" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Center">

   <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" DockPanel.Dock="Top">
      <Button Height="150" Width="200" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="30">t1</Button>
      <Button Height="150" Width="200" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="30">t2</Button>
      <Button Height="150" Width="200" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="30">t3</Button>
      <Button Height="150" Width="200" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="30">t4</Button>
   </StackPanel>

</DockPanel>
```

Comment: use `WrapPanel`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [`WrapPanel`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.wrappanel?view=net-5.0), which does exactly that:

> Positions child elements in sequential position from left to right, breaking content to the next line at the edge of the containing box.

Moreover, you could create an implicit style for your buttons, so you can set the properties once and they will be applied automatically to all buttons within the scope of the wrap panel.

```
<WrapPanel DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">
   <WrapPanel.Resources>
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Button}}">
         <Setter Property="Margin" Value="30"/>
         <Setter Property="Height" Value="150"/>
         <Setter Property="Width" Value="200"/>
      </Style>
   </WrapPanel.Resources>
   <Button>t1</Button>
   <Button>t2</Button>
   <Button>t3</Button>
   <Button>t4</Button>
</WrapPanel>
```

An alternative to setting the button `Height` and `Width` is to setting the [`ItemHeight`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.wrappanel.itemheight?view=net-5.0#System_Windows_Controls_WrapPanel_ItemHeight) and [`ItemWidth`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.wrappanel.itemwidth?view=net-5.0#System_Windows_Controls_WrapPanel_ItemWidth) properties on the wrap panel, but you have to consider the margins here (+30 dips on all four sides).

```
<WrapPanel DockPanel.Dock="Top" ItemHeight="210" ItemWidth="260">
   <WrapPanel.Resources>
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Button}}">
         <Setter Property="Margin" Value="30"/>
      </Style>
   </WrapPanel.Resources>
   <Button>t1</Button>
   <Button>t2</Button>
   <Button>t3</Button>
   <Button>t4</Button>
</WrapPanel>
```